# Event listener doesnt work on some HTML elements

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 groups of HTML buttons, all with the class `btn`.

```js
     const btn = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
        const btnArray = Array.from(btn);
        
        btnArray.forEach((item) => {
          item.addEventListener('click', () => {
            console.log('clicked');
            console.log(item.value)
          });
        });
```

```html
<div class="calculator">

    <div class="display">
        <p class="output">YES</p>
    </div>

        <div class="operations">
            <input type="submit" class="btn add" value='+'>
            <input type="submit" class="btn subtract" value='-'>
            <input type="submit" class="btn multiply" value='x'>
            <input type="submit" class="btn divide" value=&divide;>
            <input type="submit" class="btn clear" value='CLEAR'>
        </div>

        <div class="calcBody">
            <input type="submit" class="btn seven" value='7'>
            <input type="submit" class="btn eight" value='8'>
            <input type="submit" class="btn nine" value='9'>
            <input type="submit" class="btn four" value='4'>
            <input type="submit" class="btn five" value='5'>
            <input type="submit" class="btn six" value='6'>

            <input type="submit" class="btn one" value='1'>
            <input type="submit" class="btn two" value='2'>
            <input type="submit" class="btn three" value='3'>
            <input type="submit" class="btn zero" value='0'>
            <input type="submit" class="btn period" value='.'>
            <input type="submit" class="btn off" value='ON/OFF'>
        </div>
</div>
```

This works only on the buttons in the `calcBody` div and not the ones in the `operations` div.  Yet, when I `console.log(btnArray)` it shows all of the buttons (which is weird).

Can someone tell me why?  Thanks.

Comment: why do you use Array.from you can directly iterate over it in your snippet you can click every button properly

Comment: I really dont understand the problem, I tested your code and it work without any problem. Even those outside the calcBody.

Comment: "This works only on the buttons in the calcBody" How do you know? It is not right, if you will copy this code and run it in codepen it equally works for all buttons

Comment: I think It works well

Comment: For some reason, it functions in a codepen but not in the console when I open the file in chrome

Comment: It works well on my device when I open it in chrome

Comment: I just restarted my pc and now it works. That was odd but thanks for the help everyone

Answer (score 0):

works perfectly! I checked it on Google Chrome.